# Set callgrind as default tool of valgrind

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind

I need to profile a programm with callgrind which is started by some script, I dont have control over. I can tell the script to start valgrind, but I cant tell teh script which tools or parameters to use.

I found in the valgrind manual, that it is possible to use a variable `$VALGRIND_OPTS`, or a `.valgrindrc` file.
This works for tool specific options. For instance, I can write in the `~/.valgrindrc`

```
--callgrind:callgrind-out-file=<somefile>
```

And when I execute some test program a.out

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind a.out
```

the output file is written as defined in `.valgrindrc`.
But I can't specify the tool (callgrind) I want to use.

I have tried:

```
--tool=callgrind
```

and

```
--valgrind:tool=callgrind
```

Both have no effect and memcheck is started as default.
Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an alias in your shell:

```
$ alias valgrind="valgrind --tool=callgrind"
```

and call the script:

```
$ ./the_script
```

The alias will get expanded to `valgrind --tool=callgrind` inside the script.

Answer (score 1):

Since Valgrind is open source, you can get the code, modify it and build your own version that defaults to callgrind. The line that you need to modify is in coregrind/m_options.c. Here it is for 3.13:

```
const HChar *VG_(clo_toolname) = "memcheck";    // default to Memcheck
```

The following arguments are processed in `early_process_cmd_line_options` (coregrind/m_main.c). These are options that can't be read from the RC file or the environment.

```
--version"
"-v"/"--verbose"
"-q"/"--quiet"
"-h"/"--help"
"--help-debug"
"--tool"
"--max-stackframe"
"--main-stacksize"
"--max-threads"
"--sim-hints"
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! This seems to be a good solution. I will however use the solution from ks1322, since it is less effort.